# To push the Message in IBM MQ Lite Can i use FTP Protocol insted of AQMP

Tags: java, ibm-mq, amqp

I Want to push a message in IBM MQ Lite through java for that i write a code:
In that i use AQMP protocol as suggested By IBM MQ Lite Community. I want to try the same thing using the ftp protocol, I want to know weather it will work or not if it work what changes need to be done in my code.

Here is my code:

```
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.ClientOptions;

import com.ibm.mqlight.api.Delivery;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.DestinationAdapter;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.NonBlockingClient;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.NonBlockingClientAdapter;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.StringDelivery;


public class SendReceive2 
{
    public static void main(String[] cmdline) 
    {
        ClientOptions clientOpts = ClientOptions.builder().setCredentials("ad", "jms123").build();



        NonBlockingClient.create("ftp://localhost", clientOpts, new NonBlockingClientAdapter<Void>()
        {

            public void onStarted(NonBlockingClient client, Void context) 
            {
                client.subscribe("JmsQueue",  new DestinationAdapter<Void>() 
                {
                    public void onMessage(NonBlockingClient client, Void context, Delivery delivery) 
                    {
                        if (delivery.getType() == Delivery.Type.STRING)
                            System.out.println(((StringDelivery)delivery).getData());
                    }
                }, null, null);
            }
        }, null);





        NonBlockingClient.create("ftp://localhost", clientOpts, new NonBlockingClientAdapter<Void>()
        {
            public void onStarted(NonBlockingClient client, Void context) 
            {
                client.send("JmsQueue", "Jms Queue is Formed!", null);
            }

        }, null);






    }//main


}//class
```

Comment: Is there any information that indicates you can use FTP to write to a message queue? I've not heard of this. Or did you just choose an arbitrary protocol and hope that it's supported?

Comment: From [this](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/docs/amqp/?lang=java) page, there doesn't seem to be any indication that any protocol other than AMQP is supported.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am just curious to try this in alternate way,

Comment: I don't think you understand how software works. You can't just choose an arbitrary protocol and hope that your server is listening for it. Your code is irrelevant to the question, and the answer is a simple "No."

Answer (score 2):

**MQ Light only supports the amqp protocol.**  I also suggest you may want to check out [Message Hub](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/message-hub/) which can work with MQ Light API